# Javascript - Scrolltop() Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code is used for hamburger menu, but I want to know what is the code doing actually,

Also please let me know what scrolltop() does?

```
<script>
new mlPushMenu(document.getElementById('mmenu'), document.getElementById('trigger'));

$("#trigger").click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
     return false;
});
</script>
```

Regards

Comment: questions? problems? why? improve the question m8

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you need. The code is creating some new object `Menu()` with two DOM elements as parameters, and then binding a function animating a scroll to top on click to the element with ID `#trigger`.

Comment: What's the first line ???

Comment: I'm not sure if return false needs to be in there. All this does is scroll the html and body elements (it's both for cross-browser support, I think it's firefox that needs html but the others use body, or vice versa) in 0ms, or instantly. The first line is unrelated to the scroll function, I'm not sure what that's doing without context.

Comment: Now that I think about it the animate doesn't even serve a purpose if it's just happening instantly. You could just do $('html, body').scrollTop(0) to get the same effect with less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new mlPushMenu(document.getElementById('mmenu'), document.getElementById('trigger'));
```

A menu is being instantiated with two DOM nodes being injected in. Presumably the root node and the node corresponding to the hamburger menu.

```
$("#trigger").click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
     return false;
});
```

Uses JQuery to register a click event handler. The handler uses the JQuery `animate` function, presumably to ensure the user is scrolled to the top of the screen upon clicking the hamburger.

`return false` is a pattern that attempts to prevent propagation of the event. Not sure how efficacious this is.